# How can ElasticSearch use its property in the search?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

We have next data structure:

```
{
  "basicField": 23,
  "someObject": {
    22: {
      "nested": true,
      
    },
    23: {
      "nested": false,
    }
  }
}
```

Can we use `basicField` in the search? For example to filter so that `nested` inside `23` is `true` during the search.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you need to query on `basicfield` and `someObject.23.nested` fields. You can use the below search query :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "basicField": 23
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "someObject.23.nested": false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No: `basicField` can contain any value so the match should be like this: `someObject.['basicField'].nested `

Comment: @Heorhij can you please explain your requirement with the help of some sample data. Otherwise, will replacing `basicField` with `someObject.basicField.nested` in the search query will not solve your issue ?